# Can you have a Database as a return type in a Java Method?

Tags: java, database

Can you have a Database as a return type in a Java method?

Right now I'm trying to write a method that takes in three databases as parameters, and takes the information from each each table, row by row, and combines it into 1 big database. The idea is simple but the implementation is fairing difficult. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by taking 3 database as parameter? Are you referencing to DataSources?

Comment: That sounds like a Bad Idea(TM)

Comment: Are you by any chance confusing the term "database" with "table"?

Comment: No, that's not possible but you can take the database name and perform operations with those databases.

Comment: The question is quite confusing. Could you provide a sample as to what you intend to do...may be some snippets.

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing. @Coolbeans: taking in 3 databases that had been created in SQLite, to edit them within java, and then return a newly created data base.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: There are multiple tables within the databases I want to merge. I said database meaning conglomerate of tables in each one.

Comment: @Saket: For instance, you have 2 databases each with 1 table named the same thing:"Fruit." The code would go through the databases' tables, find ones similarly named, and merge them into a new database with a new table with that same name, and combine all the unique data in each databases "Fruit" table.

Answer (score 0):

What is a database?

The database is not part of your Java program (even if you think of embedded databases), from your program you only access the database through the JDBC.

With JDBC you get an `SQLConnection` and you can use it to lauch `Statement` or `PreparedStatement`. These statements provide you with a `ResultSet` (similar to a cursor in other languages) that you can use to get the different results.